# INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged always NULL

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I know I am doing something wrong here but what. Please have a look and point out my error.

I will see "Peter" in my textbox but no "Jack" after the button click.

My class

```
namespace App
{
    class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        public String Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }
    public Person()
    {
        Name = "Peter";
    }

    public void SetName(string newname)
    {
        Name = newname;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

}

My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:app="clr-namespace:App"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <app:Person x:Key="person"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBox  Width="100" Height="26" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource person}, Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23"  Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And my codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Person person;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        person = new Person();       
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.SetName("Jack");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are two Person(s). TextBox bound to Person from Grid's resources, while Button sets the Name of Person from private field. I think you should use a Person as DataContext of the Window. This will clarify your code and markup.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) & [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx), since you got some confusions in your bindings and resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two instances of Person.  PropertyChanged is not null in the static resource

This isn't really what StaticResources are for.  Get rid of the static resource, change the binding to:

```
{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}
```

and add this to your constructor:

```
DataContext = person;
```

Comment: Took me almost a bloody day to get this far. Your answer finally solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

That object person in codebehind of MainWindow is not the same object you have binding to in XAML

If you want to use that object from resources you have to find it in code behind so something like this in constructor

```
person = (Person)Resources["person"];
```